# What does this: $\{a\}\doteq\emptyset$ mean to you? Is this notation acceptable in any sense?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, second-order-cone-programming, jordan-algebras

I'm kind of embarassed for asking this question, but...

**The problem:** I'm having a hard time trying to establish a consistent notation for the spectral decomposition of the elements of a second-order cone $L_m\doteq \{(x_0,\bar{x})\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^{m-1} \colon x_0\geq \|\bar{x}\| \}$ when $m=1$. I could not find a standard treatment for this case anywhere.

**Context:** It is quite well-known that every $x\in L_m$ can be decomposed as $x=\lambda_1(x)v_1(x) + \lambda_2(x)v_2(x)$, where $\lambda_i(x)=x_0+(-1)^i\|\bar{x}\|$ and $v_i(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1,(-1)^iw)$, with $$w=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\bar{x}/\|\bar{x}\| & \text{ if } \bar{x}\neq 0\\ \text{anything s.t. }\|w\|=1 & \text{ if } \bar{x}=0\end{array}\right.$$
However, I don't see how to denote this when $m=1$. In this case, it seems that the only reasonable way of defining these guys is to set $\lambda_1(x)=x$ and $v_1(x)=1$, since a defining property of $v_1$ and $v_2$ is their "orthonormality". And from the point of view of Euclidean Jordan Algebras, $L_1$ has rank 1. But what about $\lambda_2$ and $v_2$? Actually, I want to write that $v_2$ is not defined, in such a way that I can talk about $v_1$ and $v_2$ and it's clear for everyone that they should simply ignore $v_2$.

In other words, what I want to know is:

> How to define $v_2(x)$ such that $\{v_1(x),v_2(x)\}=\{1\}$ when $m=1$, while keeping $v_1(x)v_2(x)=0$?

Even a clever notation would do the job, as long as it is not outrageous...

**My (terrible) attempt to solve the problem:** I am very inclined to make an abuse of notation and define $v_2(x)$ such that $\{v_2(x)\}\doteq\emptyset$ and $v_1(x)\doteq 1$, so I would have $\{v_1(x),v_2(x)\}=\{v_1(x)\}\cup\{v_2(x)\}=\{1\}$ and some sort of "vacuous orthogonality", but it makes me feel bad, and I have never seen this kind of abuse before. What do you think about it? Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow 100% but since $\mathbb{R}^0 = \{0\}$ can't you just say $v_2(x) = 0$?

Comment: @TrevorGunn You're right, but I forgot a detail in my question, which I now included after the edit. The fundamental property of $v_1$ and $v_2$ is their "orthonormality", so they should both have norm 1 somehow and be orthogonal. For some reason, $L_1$ is defined as $\mathbb{R}_+$, not $\mathbb{R}_+\times \{0\}$. You comment makes perfect sense, nonetheless, but it's not consistent with the other standards about $L_m$.